# Checking if parameter has been passed in windows universal c# code

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Am passing a parameter as a way to allow a user to go back and make changes

```
 private void go_back_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 

         Frame.Navigate(typeof(TruckRegistrationPage), this.truckdetails);  
    }
```

Now on the trruck registration page

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        this.changeddetails= (TruckRegistrationDetails)e.Parameter;
        //set the form fields based on the details
        if (e.Parameter) //this throws an error of boolean not casted
        {
            truck_reg_no.Text = changeddetails.reg_no;
            transporter_name.Text = truckdetails.owner_id;

             .......assign other xaml controls

        }

    }
```

The parameters am passing are of type `TruckRegistrationDetails` whic is a class containing properties as below

```
    class TruckRegistrationDetails
    {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string reg_no { get; set; }
       public int truck_category { get; set; }

        .......others
    }
```

How do i check to see if any parameters have been passed and hence assign the xaml controls value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        changeddetails = (TruckRegistrationDetails)e.Parameter;

        if (changeddetails != null) 
        {
            truck_reg_no.Text = changeddetails.reg_no;
            //do what ever you want ^^
        }
    }
```

Your check was for a boolean, but `e.Parameter` is an object. Here is the link to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs.parameter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error using this approach as at some point OnNavigatedTo is called with a NavigationEventArgs.Parameter of an empty string. This was causing a Cast exception when the object is cast to the object type I passed.
I used:

```
        if (args.Parameter is DeviceInformation)
        {
            DeviceInformation deviceInfo = (DeviceInformation)args.Parameter;
            //Do something with object
        }
```

This checks the type of object first to see if it matches the expected first, then the cast will not throw an exception.